# How to split polyline using points WITHOUT splitting at intersections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I am trying to use points to split a shapefile of lines that have been dissolved.The "SplitLinesAtPoint" tool splits at intersections in addition to the points, WHICH I DO NOT WANT. I only want to split the lines at the points and remain connected at the intersections.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include diagrams of what you are getting vs what you are wanting, please?

Answer (score 1):

as a workaround, you could creat small buffers around your points, erase those buffers from the lines, then rebuild the connections based on "extend lines" (or integrate with a small value, your buffers can be really small)

Comment: This workaround is probably the fastest.  However, it is rare that orientation is not a consideration when working with linear features and the Dissolve tool can scramble line orientations.  Only single-part outputs of the Dissolve tool likely have a useful orientation.  All multi-part lines likely have randomized orientations, especially if they form branches.  You have no control over what end of the branch is the start or end of the line segment.  I would get a part count of each line first and do some validation of multipart lines before assuming they will create the segments you want.